# SharePoint 2013 Community site + Discussion List comments should be in tree view

Tags: list-view, discussion-board, community

I have community site in which i have discussion list, for e.g take a new discussion topic in which another user made a comment in a . after that on more user is Replied on the comment , that should look in a tree view.

Comment: I found the solution How to solve the issue, Solution also work for SharePoint 2016 Discussion board and For community site .

Comment: Can you share your solution? Thanks.

Comment: Open your Discussion list in SharePoint Designer --> go to all files -->select the  Lists--> in list select the  discussion list. where you see  the ThreadedView.aspx , open it in advance mode   , and made changes to the Following  Hidden= "TRUE" change it FALSE and ReadOnly="TRUE" change this also to FALSE . .. Save the changes.